# UEFI how to add user

Tags: bios, uefi

I"m trying to add User management for default UEFI source (TiogaPass Board).

I have added  `NULL|SecurityPkg/UserIdentification/UserIdentifyManagerDxe/UserIdentifyManagerDxe.inf` to `OpenBoardPkg.dsc` and I've got an error

```
build.py...
c:\bios-git\bios\edk2-platforms\Platform\Intel\PurleyOpenBoardPkg\BoardTiogaPass\OpenBoardPkg.dsc(...): error 1001: Module type [UEFI_APPLICATION] is not supported by library instance [c:\bios-git\bios\edk2\MdePkg\Library\UefiDriverEntryPoint\UefiDriverEntryPoint.inf]
        consumed by library instance [c:\bios-git\bios\edk2\SecurityPkg\UserIdentification\UserProfileManagerDxe\UserProfileManagerDxe.inf] which is consumed by module [c:\bios-git\bios\edk2\MdeModulePkg\Application\UiApp\UiApp.inf]
```

Could you make more clear what I did wrong or how exactly can add User Management?